# In a unit circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, why can you substitute the x and y with cos and sin?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I4mcja8abDc) video he talks about a point $(x,y)$ on the unit circle can be rewritten as $(\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta))$.

However, to my understanding, $\cos$ is the adjacent side over the hypotenuse ($\frac{x}{r}$) and sin is the opposite side over the hypotenuse ($\frac{y}{r}$).

Why is it okay to substitute the values of $(x,y)$ with the values of ($\frac{x}{r}$, $\frac{y}{r}$)?

Comment: What's the length of the hypotenuse in this case?

Comment: Unit circle means that $ r=1$.

Comment: You have answered your own question r=1 so $x = \frac{x}{r}$ and $y =\frac{y}{r}$

Comment: @Arthur So this substitution only works when the radius of the circle is 1?

Comment: @RudyGoburt yes

Comment: For r not equal to 1 You need to substitute x=r cos theta and y = r sin theta

Comment: `cos is the adjacent side over the hypotenuse`: that's only the version for nursery schools. Usually, one defines the trigonometric functions as projections from a point on the unit circle onto convenient axes, and more rigourously, as analytic functions defined by power series.

Comment: But if you have $x^2 + y^2 = r$, then by noting $x' = rx$ and $y'=ry$, you get $x'^2 + y'^2=1$ so you can use this substitution.

Comment: @Bernard There is no need to call people 4-year-olds for using a definition that isn't advanced enough to your liking. It is by far the most common introductory definition, and it is enough to get the job done in this case. At least for the first quadrant.

Comment: @Arthur: I didn't call anyone 4-year old. I only recalled this is a very simplistic definition used in the early years (I myself learnt it in middle-school).

Comment: @Bernard "the version for nursery schools" means, quite unambiguously, "the version that 4-year olds use" (or maybe 5-year olds). So yes, that is what you called anyone who uses the "opposite over hypotenuse" definition.

Comment: @Arthur works for me in the other quadrants too if you allow negative adjacents . The great beauty of the trig functions is their ubiquity and how they arise in so many areas of mathematics.

Comment: That does not mean the person I'm speaking to has 4 years. One of my teachers used to speak of ‘power series for nursery schools’ when they were particularly easy to work with. I never felt offended by this wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a point $P=(x,y)$ on the unit circle but in the first quadrant, i.e. such that **both** its coordinates are positive.

Call $Q$ the projection of $P$ on the $x$-axis. The coordinates of $Q$ are $(x,0)$.

Now observe that the triangle $OPQ$ ($O$ being the origin) is right in $Q$.

So if you call $\alpha$ the angle in $O$ and recall that the length of the hypothenuse $OP$ is $1$, since it is the radius, you can recognize that
the length of $OQ$ is $\cos(\alpha)$ and the length of $PQ$ is $\sin(\alpha)$.
But this lengths are also $x$ and $y$ respectively, so that you eventually get
$$
P=(\cos(\alpha),\sin(\alpha)).
$$
So, you can now extend the $\cos$ and $\sin$ functions to angles outside the
limits $(0,\pi/2)$ (where we measure angles in *radians* instead of degrees) precisely as the coordinates of the point on the unit circle determined by the angle.

This extension of $\cos$ and $\sin$ is consistent with their usage in trigonometry which is explained in (high?) school.

Answer (score 0):

If you write $x = cos(t)$ (it is possible since $0\leqslant x \leqslant 1$), then you can remark that $y^2 = 1-x^2 = 1-\cos ^2 (t)=\sin ^2 t$, so that you can write $y=\pm \sin t$.

If $y= \sin t$ then you're finished.

If $y= -\sin t$, then you just need to note t' = -t (we have $\cos -t = \cos t$).

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Given a point on the circumference of center $(0,0)$ and radius $1$ individuated by the angle $\phi$ measured with radians, *by definition* $\cos \phi$ is the first coordinate and $\sin \phi$ is the second coordinate of that point; that is $x=\cos \phi$ and $y= \sin \phi$.